# How to store a authentication token Client side C#

Tags: c#, authentication, token

I have a web service and after the login I create a token for all the following requests. The token is valid for 48h, so the user doesn't have to login everytime a request is made. Now everytime the programm is restarted the user needs to login again. (Not the best UX) I want to work on this problem now. How can I store the token on the client side in a way I can read it at the start of the program.

I thought about saving it in a file. (Binary or something similar) The problem here is if I can read it everybody else can. The solution for this would be to salt and hash the token before writing it into the file.(of cause use a random salt) This solution does not have the best performence because I have to unhash it at every start.

Is there any other possible solution to solve my problem?

Comment: How can you decrypt something that has been hashed? Anyway, can you not tie a token to an IP address? That will obviously not help those who are using a dynamic IP address but maybe that's OK.

Comment: Nice idea to tie it to the IP address. 
I didn't really mean decrypt more like unhash. going to edit this.

Comment: You can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This depends on the platform since different platforms have different ways of safe storage.  "This solution does not have the best performence because I have to unhash it at every start" How long will this take to be a problem? You might want to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/intro-to-secure-windows-app-development) first

Comment: The platform is a usual desktop pc or notebook.

Comment: There's no such thing as "unhashing", which is one of the main the points. Hashing is a one-way process.

Comment: you are right. I had a thought problem. hashing and comparing.

Comment: The Data Protection API is for such data and is encapsulated in .net by ProtectedData class